# Programming Languages required to develop a website like Imgur?

Tags: html, web-services, web, imgur

I'm new to web development. So far, I have a good idea of HTML and CSS.

1) I would like to know what are programming languages are required to develop a website like Imgur and what's the role of each language that will be used.

2) Assuming that a user has just uploaded an Image to Imgur, What would be the required steps to generate a unique HMTL file for that particular Image.

Comment: It should be easy to research literally all of this via your search engine of choice. There's really no one language that would be best for it, and any suggestions would likely be out of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need:

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. A server-side framework (e.g., PHP, Ruby on Rails, etc.)
4. Most likely Javascript (but you might be able to get by without it)
5. A database backend, such as PostgreSQL or MongoDB

You wouldn't need individual HTML sites. When someone goes to http://www.yoursite.com/image/1, the backend (usually .htaccess in Apache) will process it and turn it into /image.php?id=1, which PHP (or another framework) then uses to create an image-specific HTML page.

Good luck!

-totallyuneekname

Comment: How can I convert "http://www.yoursite.com/image/1" to  "/image.php?id=1" or vice versa

Comment: It depends. If you have Apache, (a really common web server) you would use the .htaccess file (as mentioned above). If you use a different web server, you would have to look it up (that's what Stackoverflow is for!).

Answer (score 0):

1) You're probably best looking into either PHP or ASP for a server side language. Also learn SQL, as you'll need to store information about the images somewhere, and a database will probably be best.

2)

- Get unique ID of image from URL
- Get the address of corresponding image from database, along with title, description etc.
- Fill data into relevant parts of your template, i.e image address inside image tag, title in h1 and title tags etc.

Comment: Would it be better for the database to be accessed every time the HTML paged is viewed or should a permanent html page be generated ?

Comment: You won't need to generate a permanent page. This wouldn't be possible anyway as the information on the page would be constantly changing if you're displaying times viewed, comments etc.

Comment: Server-side frameworks such as [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) often expose a caching mechanism to store the some or all of the page's HTML once it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to create new HTML files every time you want someone to view an image. You can just have 1 `php` file which loads something from a database which gets what you are looking for.

For this you'll probably need: `HTML`, `CSS`, `MySQLi\pdo`, `javascript`.

It might also be beneficial not just for you to learn a framework, but to work on one too, as it can help you in big projects.

One I regularly work with is [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and it has a lot of good documentation to read through.

Comment: To be fair, OP said "to generate a unique HTML file" which both is correct and incorrect, depending on how you look at it.